# Instance methods in Ruby Strings?

Tags: ruby, string, class, instance

I`ve been asked to make some functions, and afterwards make them available as instance methods in the String class. How can I do that in Ruby?

I made the functions inside a module. The skeleton is something close to this:

```
module My_module
def xxxx(string)
end
(...)
end

class String
  include My_module
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ruby, built-in classes can be opened and modified which is a powerful technique, but  it’s considered bad form to add methods to built-in classes without having a really good reason for doing so.

You need to do something like this with your custom defined functions(here I defined my custom `palindrome` function inside the String class.

```
class String
   # Returns true if the string is its own reverse.
   def palindrome?
     self == self.reverse
   end
end
```

Doing so you can directly call the method on the String object.

for e.g:

```
"level".palindrome? # => true
```

Comment: Thanks! But, should I retype the same code I did in the module inside strings?

Comment: yes! you have code except there is no need of sending a string as an argument in the the method definition as its defined inside the String class.

Comment: perfect, got the idea, now my Rspec tests finnaly went green!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it exactly as you did:

```
module MyModule
  def speak(name)
    puts "#{self} the String says hello to #{name}"
  end
end

class String
  include MyModule
end

"Joe".speak("danslz")



--output:--
Joe the String says hello to danslz
```

> I`ve been asked to make some functions,

Modules are a good way to organize functions.

> except there is no need of sending a string as an argument

Unless of course the method takes a string as an argument, e.g String#new, String#[], String#<=>, etc., etc.